# Can't compare size of ArrayList in subclass

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class with an ArrayList and 2 subclasses.

I add another element to the ArrayList in the first subclass, but when I look up the size in the second subclass it still says, that the ArrayList has size 0.

---

class:

```
ArrayList <ClientManager> clientList = new ArrayList <ClientManager>();
```

---

subclass 1:

```
clientList.add(clientManager);
System.out.println(clientList.size());
```

In the first subclass I add an element and check, if the size actually increased.

---

subclass 2:

actual code:

```
while (clientList.size() == 0);
```

test 1:

```
while (clientList.size() == 0) {
    System.out.println(clientList.size());
}
```

test 2:

```
while (true) {
            System.out.println(clientList.size());
        }
```

In the second subclass I try to compare the size, but for some reason it doesn't acknowledge the change.

When I tested it by printing the size, it always printed '0'.

But when I do the printing with an infinte while-loop it prints the size correctly.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Cab you provide us more code ?

Comment: @Miha test1: while (clientList.size() == 0) means while size is not 0, do not print size. So you should not expect printing sth different from zero. This is why you get the size with infinity loop.

Comment: @Sedat Polat You're right. Didn't think about that, but I wanted to show that in one case, it has the correct size and in the other case it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you instantiate any object of a class it allocates memory for each and every non static member. So your subclass 1 object has one clientList and subclass 2 object has different object for different memory allocation.

Comment: Except¨this introduces shadowing and breaks polymorphism and generally is not recommended. Static methods are not part of dynamic binding. I think static members should be treated the same as private members when inheriting to prevent exactly this.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot that. Absolutely right. Editing the answer.

Comment: I used static for now and will see, if I can rewrite it later on. Though it only works, if I leave the printing in the loop.